# Phone validation regex needs to allow whitespace and parantheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How do I modify my current regular expression `/^[0-9+-]{6,20}$/` so it allows whitespaces and ()?

I've tried `\s` but without luck: `/^[0-9+-]\s{6,20}$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will accept arbitrary whitespace and the named punctuation, and still requires there to be between 6 and 20 digits.

```
/^[\s()+-]*([0-9][\s()+-]*){6,20}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `\s` and the round brackets to the character class (inside the square brackets) like this: `/^[0-9+\-\s()]{6,20}$/`

Comment: Wrong because you didn't escape the `-` and didn't put it at the beginning or end.

Comment: Actually that will not fail. You need not to escape characters inside a character class (`[]`). Even characters like `*` or `.` will match the actual character inside it.

Comment: Yeah, but you need to put - last to avoid ambiguous

Comment: No, @xanatos is right. I've tested it and FireBug complains about an invalid character range. I've edited the escape.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you seek:

```
/^[0-9() +-]{6,20}$/
```

It's not perfect though as it would allow strings such as `(((())))`, you should give a more specific template (`(###)###-####` for example) and work according to that. The above code does exactly what you asked.

Comment: I'll suggest /\+?^[0-9() -]{6,20}$/

Comment: No reason for that. The OP never specified exactly what type of number he's targeting. Like I stated in my answer, he should define a stricter template and work towards that.

Comment: I though "+" cannot be inside the number, only in the begging, but probably you are right and strict template will be better

Comment: For all I know he might want to target arithmetical operations. `5+3-(5+4-1)`.

Comment: Sorry I missed something, but topic was about phones.

Comment: Why would he want to target arithmetical operations on phone numbers?

Comment: I'm just saying, he should define a clear pattern, not make up ambiguous definitions and hope for the best.

Comment: I don't know what kind of phone number he's targetting, but in some countries (eg UK) the area code and local number can vary in length, so a fixed template would be inappropriate.

Comment: Spudley got it right, the site are targeting 9 countries. we allow for country codes hence the + and (), after that we dont got no requirments exept the the input it numbers.